# Blog and syntax coloration

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog

Today we released a blog article on a technical subject. It includes C code.

I was wondering if this was possible to have some syntax coloration for those block of codes? In fact, we do have a wonderful system on the stacks, so why not on the blog? I know the system is not the same, but who knows?

Answer (score 2):

The [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) plugin is installed and activated for you to use.

Comment: @Mvy - does this do it the way you require?

Comment: I have to check it when I have some time.

Comment: Still no syntax highlighting for code block within Information Security.